# Localized Android app without using "res" folder. Is there a downside?

Tags: android, localization, unity-game-engine, google-play

I am developing a game with Unity 3D and want to use custom code to get strings in the various languages I will be supporting.  I've read articles about using the Android "res/values-xx/" directories (such as this page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).  If I do not store my translated strings in this way is there a downside?  My main concern is whether the Google Play store may not know what languages my app is localized for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the play store, but as far as i remember you can just configure in wich countries your app should be aviable, also you can provide different screenshots and descriptions for each country/language.

But you should make sure that your application automatically uses the system language of the android device. Check: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage%28%29

Thats what the developer guidelines say..
http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/localizing.html

Comment: So if I localized the store description and made the app available in all countries everyone would see it in their stores and not be able to tell if it is in their language until they download it and try it?